# Laravel Reload only View Data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

in my Laravel application I've a simple ajax request which adds a new comment to the database. Now I will reload only the div where the comments listed with the new data. How dose it works?

Thank you for help and sorry for my bad english :)

Request

```
function comment(user, project, token) {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/comment',
        data: {'project': project, '_token': token, 'author': user, 'content': $('#comment-' + project).val()},
        success: function () {
            console.log('success');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
            console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment section

```
<div class="panel-google-plus-comment">
                        <img class="img-circle" src="https://mcapi.ca/avatar/{{ Auth::user()->name }}"
                             alt="User Image" height="46" width="46"/>
                        <div class="panel-google-plus-textarea">
                            <textarea rows="4" id="comment-{{$project->id}}"></textarea>
                            <button type="submit" class="[ btn btn-success disabled ]" onclick="comment('{{Auth::user()->id}}', '{{$project->id}}', '{{csrf_token()}}')">Post comment</button>
                            <button type="reset" class="[ btn btn-default ]">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show us your code/what you've tried :)

Comment: I can only send my Ajax request. I just need the theoretical way.

Comment: Well, the best way would be to "append" the comment. Grab the div, use jQuery and manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Look at the post :)

Comment: What do you mean with "manipulate the DOM"?